# Tracing a foreign android program or app with gdb - loading symbols?

Tags: android, gdb, debug-symbols

I am trying to use gdb for investigating an app I don't have any sources for.

Using the tools provided by Android NDK I already figured out how to start gdbserver on the device, afterwards start the correct gdbclient on the PC and how to connect both via remote mode.

The problem is now that if I try to set a breakpoint on a method like `fopen` that belongs to a standard library like cstdlib gdb refuses to do so as it misses the symbol files.

**Where can I find the correct symbol files (concrete subdir of Android NDK?) and how to I load them into gdb when running in remote mode (gdb commands)?**

PC platform is Windows and Android is Galaxy Nexus phone running 4.1.2

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint on something from bionic. Or Log.d.

Comment: If you simply need the source code, and if you have or are willing to gain access to the apk (via rooting), you can unpack it to view the source.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I did anything with gdb, but your question caught my attention.  I don't have the NDK installed, so I can't speak for the location of the files.  But I found some info on loading missing symbols.

This tutorial looks somewhat like what you're trying to do:
http://marcioandreyoliveira.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-debug-striped-programs-with-gdb.html

But it assumes that you built your binaries and can build one with symbols.  I'm not sure if it will work to load only cstdlib, etc, but it's a start.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer wasn't much helpful. As I wrote in my question it is a foreign app, therefore I don't build anything and I therefore can't just rebuild the app. Additionally the post does not answer where to get the symbol files from.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it should have been a comment rather than an answer.  You did ask "and how to I load them into gdb when running in remote mode (gdb commands)".